# Complete example of (N)RVO

Tags: c++, move-semantics, nrvo

I've been reading about (N)RVO and would like one, complete scenario description. I hope this question will serve other C++ -learners to clarify their ideas.

Suppose this scenario:

```
string get_string() {
    string x("racecar");
    //work on x...
    return x;
}

string a( get_string() );
string b = get_string();
```

Please disregard the C++11 move-semantics for a moment.

- If no (N)RVO is performed, how many constructors/assignments/destructors will be
  executed? (please point out, to which objects to they refer)
- What changes if (N)RVO is applied?
- Finally, how does the situation change in C++11 assuming, that `std::string` supports
  move-semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Inside `get_string`, one string object (x) will be constructed using the constructor which takes a `const char*`.

2) When the function returns, the string constructed inside will be copy constructed to a temporary string object in the caller's space.

3) The temporary will be copy constructed to `a`.

4) See 1

5) See 2

6) See 3, but the copy will go to `b`

With RVO, 2 an 5 can be eliminated by constructing the temporary inside the function via an invisible reference.  With further copy elision (not RVO), 3 and 6 can be eliminated.  So that leaves us with 2 constructions, both using the `const char*` constructor.

With C++11 move semantics, the situation doesn't change at all if the compiler was good enough to get all the copy elision done.  If copy elision isn't done, then 2, 3, 5 and 6 still exist, but become moves instead of copies.  Unlike copy elision though, these moves are not an optional optimization.  A conforming compiler must perform them, assuming it didn't already perform copy elision.

Comment: RVO just elminiates copies (2) and (5). Copies (3) and (6) can be eliminated by the normal elision of temporaries independently of (n)RVO being applied.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: You're right.  I tend to conflate RVO to include general copy elision because I learned about both at the same time.

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed to know, thanks :) Do you have any links to topics you (perhaps) didn't mention in your answer?